# SwiftUI background image moves when keyboard shows

Tags: image, swiftui, keyboard

I have an image background, which should stay in place when the keyboard shows, but instead it moves up together with everything on the screen. I saw someone recommend using `ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)`, and this question [Simple SwiftUI Background Image keeps moving when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028845/simple-swiftui-background-image-keeps-moving-when-keyboard-appears), but neither works for me. Here is my super simplified code sample. Please keep in mind that while the background should remain unchanged, the content itself should still avoid the keyboard as usual.

```
struct ProfileAbout: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("write something", text: $text)
            Spacer()
            Button("SomeButton") {}
        }
        .background(
            Image("BackgroundName")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a possible salvation:

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
    
    @State var valueOfTextField: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            Image("Your Image name here").resizable().scaledToFill().ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ZStack {
                
                if verticalSizeClass == UserInterfaceSizeClass.regular { TextFieldSomeView.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) }
                else { TextFieldSomeView }
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { print("OK!") }, label: { Text("OK").padding(.horizontal, 80.0).padding(.vertical, 5.0).background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(5.0) }).padding()
                    
                }

            }
            .position(x: proxy.size.width/2, y: proxy.size.height/2)
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var TextFieldSomeView: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            TextField("write something", text: $valueOfTextField).padding(5.0).background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(5.0).padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
  
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Both of these make the content ignore keyboard too. I need the content to avoid keyboard, while the background image should stay in place.

Comment: What you mean "Both of these make the content ignore keyboard too"? I think you want a view that it does not change its depending of keyboard is active or not! If that is so, then the code and answer is correct! otherwise give more information of what you really want?

Comment: Edited the question to contain more code - I have a button at the bottom. Button should go up when the keyboard is shown. Background picture should stay unchanged. If I use your code the button stays hidden behind the keyboard

Comment: @f3dm76: New update available in my answer

Answer (score 1):

u can use `GeometryReader`

get parent View size

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct KeyboardAdaptive: ViewModifier {
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .padding(.bottom, keyboardHeight)
                .onReceive(Publishers.keyboardHeight) {
                    self.keyboardHeight = $0
                }
        }
    }
}

extension Publishers {
    static var keyboardHeight: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        let willShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { $0.keyboardHeight }
        let willHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { _ in CGFloat(0) }
        
        return MergeMany(willShow, willHide)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

```
extension View {
    func keyboardAdaptive() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: KeyboardAdaptive())
    }
}
```

```
struct ProfileAbout: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("write something", text: $text)
            Spacer()
            Button("SomeButton") {}
        }
        .background(
            Image("BackgroundName")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        )
        .keyboardAdaptive()
    }
}
```